# How to have .click on two functions using the same button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code has the following button:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnEnviar" name="btnEnviar" value="Enviar">
```

And in the JavaScript I've got this function:

```
$('#btnEnviar').click( function(){ });
```

I need to know to use two functions using the same button id "btnEnviar", and event ".click".

For example:

```
$('#btnEnviar').click( function(1){ });
               .click( function(2){ });
```

Comment: Why can't it all go in the same click event?

Comment: See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nk9Lejto/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call both functions in the handler:

```
$("#btnEnviar").click(function() {
    function1();
    function2();
});
```

or bind multiple handlers:

```
$("#btnEnviar").click(function1).click(function2);
```